# How to unescape CSS

Tags: html, css, go

The text being stored in the database also includes the CSS styling.

```
<p>ABC&nbsp;&nbsp;| Min. XYZ&nbsp;
<style type="text/css"><!--td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}-->
</style>
<span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:3011,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:[null,2,16777215],&quot;9&quot;:1,&quot;10&quot;:1,&quot;11&quot;:4,&quot;12&quot;:0,&quot;14&quot;:[null,2,0]}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;PQR&quot;}" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">PQR</span></p>
```

To get rid of &nbsp I have used html.Unescape() and it works perfectly fine.

When fetched from database I want to display it in this format : `ABC | Min. XYZ PQR`

But the actual result (after using `html.Unescape()`) is :

```
ABC | Min. XYZ
<style type="text/css">
    <!--td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}-->
</style>
<span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:3011,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:[null,2,16777215],&quot;9&quot;:1,&quot;10&quot;:1,&quot;11&quot;:4,&quot;12&quot;:0,&quot;14&quot;:[null,2,0]}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;PQR&quot;}" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">PQR</span></p>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What output are you hoping for?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must also include the relevant code.

Comment: Please show us in code where and how you used html.Unescape().

Comment: i recently used this lib to manipulate html markups https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery

Comment: [bluemonday](https://github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday) can also be used to strip HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems simple but requires you to do 3 things:

1. Strip all HTML tags like `<p>` and `<style type="text/css">`
2. Unescape HTML entities like `&nbsp;`
3. Replace newlines, multiple spaces, and non-breaking spaces (`U+00A0`) with single spaces

You can do this with the following with [`github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday`](https://github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday), `html` and `strings`:

```
// Your input text
input := `<p>ABC&nbsp;&nbsp;| Min. XYZ&nbsp;
<style type="text/css"><!--td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}-->
</style>
<span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:3011,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:[null,2,16777215],&quot;9&quot;:1,&quot;10&quot;:1,&quot;11&quot;:4,&quot;12&quot;:0,&quot;14&quot;:[null,2,0]}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;PQR&quot;}" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">PQR</span></p>`

// Strip all HTML tags
p := bluemonday.StrictPolicy()

output := p.Sanitize(input)

// Unescape HTML entities
output = html.UnescapeString(output)

// Condense whitespace
output = strings.Join(strings.Fields(strings.TrimSpace(output)), " ")
```

output is now `ABC | Min. XYZ PQR`

For the last step, using `strings.Fields` looks cleaner than using a regexp since `\s` doesn't cover non-breaking spaces (`U+00A0`) and thus requires the following:

```
// Leading and trailing spaces
output = regexp.MustCompile(`^[\s\p{Zs}]+|[\s\p{Zs}]+$`).ReplaceAllString(output, "")
// middle spaces
output = regexp.MustCompile(`[\s\p{Zs}]{2,}`).ReplaceAllString(output, " ")
```

See more on matching whitespace here: [How to remove redundant spaces/whitespace from a string in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290693/how-to-remove-redundant-spaces-whitespace-from-a-string-in-golang)

Finally, you can combine the above into a function as follows in [`github.com/grokify/gotilla/html/htmlutil`](https://github.com/grokify/gotilla/blob/master/html/htmlutil/htmlutil.go)

```
var bluemondayStrictPolicy = bluemonday.StrictPolicy()

func HTMLToTextCondensed(s string) string {
    return strings.Join(
        strings.Fields(
            strings.TrimSpace(
                html.UnescapeString(
                    bluemondayStrictPolicy.Sanitize(s),
                ),
            )),
        " ",
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using modern browsers, here's the code from [devtools-frontend](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend):

```js
// front_end/panels/elements/StylesSidebarPane.ts
export function unescapeCssString(input: string): string {
  // https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#consume-escaped-code-point
  const reCssEscapeSequence = /(?<!\\)\\(?:([a-fA-F0-9]{1,6})|(.))[\n\t\x20]?/gs;
  return input.replace(reCssEscapeSequence, (_, $1, $2) => {
    if ($2) {  // Handle the single-character escape sequence.
      return $2;
    }
    // Otherwise, handle the code point escape sequence.
    const codePoint = parseInt($1, 16);
    const isSurrogate = 0xD800 <= codePoint && codePoint <= 0xDFFF;
    if (isSurrogate || codePoint === 0x0000 || codePoint > 0x10FFFF) {
      return '\uFFFD';
    }
    return String.fromCodePoint(codePoint);
  });
}
```

**NOTE: Above codes will not work for Safari** because Safari doesn't support regex lookbehind :( However, the same goal can be achieved by simply replacing lookbehind with lookahead.
Here's my implementation:

```js
function unescapeCssStringSafari(input: string): string {
  // https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#consume-escaped-code-point
  // return input
  const reCssEscapeSequence = /\\(?:([a-fA-F0-9]{1,6})|(.))[\n\t\x20]?/gs;
  let lastPos = 0;
  return input.replace(reCssEscapeSequence, (_, $1, $2, curPos) => {
    if (input.slice(lastPos, curPos) === "\\\\") {
      lastPos = curPos;
      return _;
    }
    lastPos = curPos;
    if ($2) {
      // Handle the single-character escape sequence.
      return $2;
    }
    // Otherwise, handle the code point escape sequence.
    const codePoint = parseInt($1, 16);
    const isSurrogate = 0xd800 <= codePoint && codePoint <= 0xdfff;
    if (isSurrogate || codePoint === 0x0000 || codePoint > 0x10ffff) {
      return "\uFFFD";
    }
    return String.fromCodePoint(codePoint);
  });
}
```

And you may want to detect the browser type:

```
function unescapeCssStringGeneral(input: string) {
  const fn = (window as any).safari
    ? unescapeCssStringSafari
    : unescapeCssString;
  return fn(input);
}
```

Yes! Let's do some unit tests (also took from [devtools-frontend](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend)):

```js
import { assert } from "chai";

assert.strictEqual(
  unescapeCssStringGeneral(
    String.raw`"I\F1 t\EB rn\E2 ti\F4 n\E0 liz\E6 ti\F8 n\2603 \1F308  can be \t\r\ic\k\y"`
  ),
  '"I\xF1t\xEBrn\xE2ti\xF4n\xE0liz\xE6ti\xF8n\u2603\u{1F308} can be tricky"'
);
assert.strictEqual(
  unescapeCssStringGeneral(String.raw`"_\DBFF_\\DBFF_\\\DBFF_\\\\DBFF_\\\\\DBFF_"`),
  '"_\uFFFD_\\DBFF_\\\\DBFF_\\\\\\DBFF_\\\\\\\\DBFF_"'
);
assert.strictEqual(
  unescapeCssStringGeneral(String.raw`"\0_\DBFF_\DFFF_\110000"`),
  '"\uFFFD_\uFFFD_\uFFFD_\uFFFD"',
  "U+0000, lone surrogates, and values above U+10FFFF should become U+FFFD"
);
assert.strictEqual(
  unescapeCssStringGeneral(String.raw`"_\D83C\DF08_"`),
  '"_\uFFFD\uFFFD_"',
  "surrogates should not be combined"
);
assert.strictEqual(
  unescapeCssStringGeneral('"_\\41\n_\\41\t_\\41\x20_"'),
  '"_A_A_A_"',
  "certain trailing whitespace characters should be consumed as part of the escape sequence"
);
```