# How to remove duplicated spaces from a string without removing new lines characters

Tags: string, go

I can read here: [How to remove redundant spaces/whitespace from a string in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290693/how-to-remove-redundant-spaces-whitespace-from-a-string-in-golang) that I can use regex or `strings.Fields` to remove duplicated spaces from strings.

I need to know a fast (performances matter here) way to remove ONLY duplicated (or more) spaces from a (maybe long) string and NOT remove new lines characters like `\n`.

Example:

1. "I have`[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]`duplicated spaces`[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]`as you can see" => "I have`[SPACE]`duplicated spaces`[SPACE]`as you can see"
2. "I have`[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]`new lines\n\ntoo" => "I have`[SPACE]`new lines\n\ntoo"

Answer (score 2):

```
strings.ReplaceAll(strings.Join(strings.FieldsFunc(text, func(r rune) bool {
    if r == '\n' {
        return false
    }
    return unicode.IsSpace(r)
} ), " ")," \n", "\n")
```

```
r := regexp.MustCompile("( ){2,}")
r.ReplaceAllString(input, " ")
```

`strings.FieldsFunc` seems to be a lot faster than regexp

```
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
BenchmarkRegexp
BenchmarkRegexp-8         841189          1299 ns/op
BenchmarkFields
BenchmarkFields-8        3375925           355.4 ns/op
```

Comment: does your `BenchmarkFields` also account for putting the string slice back together? seems like an important detail

Comment: @blackgreen yes, also edited in answer to show exact code used. But input text was pretty short so I'd recommend to run benchmarks with your samples.

Comment: @blackgreen I was able to increase performance of regexp changing `r.ReplaceAllString(input, "$1")` `"$1" => " "`  but still nearly 4 times slower.